# StepScope vs JobScope

Tags: spring

I went through all the pages in the internet about the StepScope and JobScope and still not sure what is the clear difference and where to use which one

My Understanding

1. `StepScope` : Different instance for each step execution.
2. `JobScope`  : Only one instance per executing job.

Can someone please explain it clearly?

Thanks

Comment: What isn't clear about it? One is per step, the other per job? A job can have multiple steps, something used multiple steps inside a job will get multiple instances when stepscoped, just 1 instance when job scoped?

Comment: @M.Deinum If that's the case, why the JobExecution Context cannot be retrieved in all the steps. I'm unable to retrieve JobExecution parameters neither the JobExecution context in skipPolicy class

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong, I used it multiple occasions without issues.